# PHP in_array_keys-like function

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a similar function like `in_array()` but that can check array keys, instead of values?

Comment: -1 because the php.net page for `in_array` links to `array_key_exists`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comment you left on [@Alexander Gessler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474496/php-in-array-keys-like-function/6474505#6474505), here's a small function you could use:

```
function array_keys_exist(array $keys, array $array)
{
  // Loop through all the keys and if one doesn't exist, return false.
  foreach ( $keys as $key )
    if ( ! array_key_exists($key, $array) )
      return false;

  // All keys were found.
  return true;
}

if ( array_keys_exist(array('abc', 'xyz'), array('abc' => 343, 'xyz' => 3434, 'def' => 343434)) )
  echo 'All keys exist!';
```

The function above called `array_keys_exist` loops through all the keys in the keys array calling PHP's `array_key_exists` function and if a key isn't found the function returns false (or true if all the keys were found in the array).

Answer (score 8):

It is named [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Comment: Good answer, great function. :)

Comment: but it's not the same, you can only check a string

Comment: @Alex: From [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php): `key can be any value possible for an array index.`

Comment: so can I use `array_key_exists(array('abc', 'xyz'), array('abc' => 343, 'xyz' => 3434, 'def' => 343434)` ?

Comment: @Alex the documentation doesn't say, so I'm assuming no, but you could always just use the function in a for loop to get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

There happens to be just that:

```
array_key_exists()
```

Found on the php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php